# Piecewise Function Error

Tags: plotting

I want to plot such a figure

[image]

I used command `Plot[Piecewise[{{1,x<0},{x,x=0},{1,x>0}}],{x,-3,3}]`.

But it shows wrong results.

Comment: Lookup `=` vs `==`.

Comment: @Kuba, Okay, but we can not not see the line to point (0,0)

Comment: Correct but that was solved by kglr now. `Plot` is not likely to exactly "hit" `x==0` so that is why it looks like a straight line.

Comment: @Kuba, also, Thanks a lot,  Before only do it in PPTX.... .:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ParametricPlot[{ {x, 2}, {0, 2 Rescale[x, {-3, 3}]}}, {x, -3, 3}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 16], Style["y", 16]}, 
     AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], 
     Ticks -> None, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
     AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> {{.2, .5}, {0., .5}}, 
     ImageSize -> Large ]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, 0}, {x, 2}, {0, 2 Rescale[x, {-3, 3}]}}, {x, -3, 3}, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can `Plot`  two `Piecewise` functions with the option `ExclusionsStyle`:

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {2, x > 0}}], 
  Piecewise[{{2, x < 0}, {0, x > 0}}]}, {x, -3, 3}, Axes -> False, 
  ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: where is error in my code?

Comment: why we can not see line to (0,0) using my method??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, (1)  you should use `x ==0 ` in the middle piece as Kuba commented (2) even then, it gives a single horizontal line at y==1 with a gap at x==0 .

Comment: how can we add -> x, ->y; symbols??

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, you mean `Plot[{Piecewise[{{0, x < 0}, {2, x > 0}}], 
  Piecewise[{{2, x < 0}, {0, x > 0}}]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.04], 
 Ticks -> None, ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> {{.2, .5}, {0., .5}}]`?

Comment: great, very useful code!!!

Comment: is there a very easy way to add text in plotting file. for example in the middle point, we write (x=0, y=0),   in other point we write (x=0, y=1)?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

```
Graphics[{Black, AbsoluteThickness@3, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 3}}], 
  Line[{{-3, 3}, {3, 3}}], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
  Arrow[{{-5, 0}, {5, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 3}, {0, 4}}], 
  Text[Style["x", 16, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"], {4.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image]

Here is alternatives:

```
Show[Plot[UnitStep[x], {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness@3}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
 Plot[UnitStep[-x], {x, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness@3}], 
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@3, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Or

```
Show[Plot[0, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness@3}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}], 
 Plot[1, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness@3}], 
 AxesStyle -> AbsoluteThickness@3, Ticks -> None, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or using `Graphics`

```
Graphics[{Black, AbsoluteThickness@3, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}], 
  Line[{{-3, 0}, {3, 0}}], Line[{{-3, 2}, {3, 2}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: you answer is also very helpful, thank you!